# Using JMF with jffMPEG

Tags: java, jmf

I`m programing in Java with Eclipse. On my project i use JMF in my java application. I need to play mp4 files so i am trying to add jffMPEG to use with JMF but meanwhile with no success. I followed [this](http://jffmpeg.sourceforge.net/download.html) tutorial.

But on second step, register the following "Demultiplexers" i get

`"JMF Registry Error - Could not add item".`

Can anyoune please help me playing MP4 in jPanel or refer me to good tutorial how to use jffMPEG in java.